# wrap text fields on responsive template

Tags: html, css

I am trying to find the correct tag to wrap content on a page on a responsive template.

The following page:

> http://localbutler.co.uk/index.php/user.html

when resized to the width of a mobile does not wrap the input fields in "shopper information" and "bill to" sections. Instead it just truncates the content.

An example of where it works is:

> http://demo.gavick.com/joomla25/storefront/index.php/virtuemart/shop-front-page/cart

I have tried comparing the two and can see the word-wrap property but this is set to "break-word" and is the same on both pages.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check Twitter Bootstrap. There is very easy to use grid system ( http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid ) which might do what you want.

Comment: Thanks but both urls above are based on the same template layout and I believe it is a very simple tag addition/alteration which will achieve the desired result.